# Changing CSS code with JQuery click function

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

HTML Code:

```
    <div id="r1242">
        <img class="trans" src="http://sakshamcomputer.com/images/printerLogo.jpg"/>
        <div class="labels" id="p1242">
            <strong>Available Printers:</strong><br><br>
            Lanier LD075 Rm1242<br><br>
            Rm1242_Ricoh_Aficio_MP_7502
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
    #r1242 #p1242 {
         display:none;
    }
```

JQuery Code:

```
    $('div .trans').click(
          function() {
             $('#p1242').css("display","block");
          }
    });
```

I want to use JQuery to change the value of "display" in my CSS code. I've tried a variety of things in JQuery for the first reference to the element, such as "$('#r1242 #p1242')", "$('#p1242')", etc. How can I properly change the value of display?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra curly bracket:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div .trans').click(function(){
         $('#p1242').css("display","block");
});
});
```

Head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="main.css"/> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CMJb3/

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle, but for some reason when I apply the changes to my syntax error in my code itself, and I open it in the browser, the list of available printers still do not show up.

Could this possibly be due to an error in the linking in <head> in HTML?

I have the following:
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="main.css"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

Comment: @JeffreyTai, maybe you forgot to include jquery on your code...try the order that i suggest you...cheers

Comment: Strange, I fixed the order and added the new script type and source. The list of available printers still doesn't appear.

Comment: Local server I believe. I'm just coding on Notepad++ on my local computer. I placed my entire code into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CMJb3/. In here, you can see the printers on the left (the formatting is off right now). You can see that two of the printers will have hovering effects, and the far left printer will have its list of available printers stay after being clicked on. It's working in here, yet on my local computer, when I open the file up in the Google Chrome browser, it doesn't work.

Comment: My apologies, I saw that the previous updates to the jsfiddle didn't apply. I forked it and here's the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/MJr7u/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your jQuery code causing it not to run.  You have an additional closing curly `}` bracket in the bottom closing statement.  Remove it and it works:

```
$('div .trans').click(
      function() {
         $('#p1242').css("display","block");
      }
);
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utHgS/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` function instead of adding `css` through `jQuery`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/C3eKn/1/)**

```
$('.trans').click(function(){
  $('#p1242').show();
});
```